# Debugging script, issue in reading in files at start

Tags: r, linux, debugging

I am trying to debug a .R script, going through line by line to see where the bug is.

I am at the part where I input the datasets but am having trouble understanding what the code below is doing.

```
gtfile =grep("gt=",commandArgs())
if (length(gtfile)==0) { stop ("specify genotype file (gt=filename)\nRun script without arguments to see all options\n") }
gtfile=sub("gt=","", commandArgs()[gtfile])
```

Should I just be able to read in my gt file name below:

```
gt=read.table("~/clean.tab")
```

If I read the gt file in like above, I should then modify the mode to expect the gt object, like below?

```
gtfile =grep("gt",commandArgs())
if (length(gtfile)==0) { stop ("specify genotype file (gt=filename)\nRun script without arguments to see all options\n") }
gtfile=sub("gt","", commandArgs()[gtfile])
```

I get the following error, which makes me think it is not reading in the file gt as I hoped.

```
Error: specify genotype file (gt=filename)
Run script without arguments to see all options
```

Any advice on what the first block of code is doing would be appreciated.

I have modified the code block and read in the file.
I was expecting the gt file to be read in, then run the code block to grep the needed parts within the file.

Comment: The first chunk you posted checks if the command line argument `gt` was supplied when R was invoked. It looks like you ran this script in interactive session and set `gt` yourself. Then you don't need to care about the first chunk of code you posted

Comment: Correct, it is expecting me to set gt myself. I could like to run the first code chunk to make sure the any transfermation from that code is applied to the gt object.

Comment: Woudl you agree that I should just have to do 
gt=read.table("~/clean.tab") gtfile =grep("gt=",commandArgs())
if (length(gtfile)==0) { stop ("specify genotype file (gt=filename)\nRun script without arguments to see all options\n") }
gtfile=sub("gt=","", commandArgs()[gtfile]) And it should read in the object gt and then transform?

Comment: you only need `gt=read.table("~/clean.tab") `

Comment: It is odd, it still won't read it in correctly. gt=read.table("~/clean.tab")                     
gtfile =grep("gt=",commandArgs())       gtfile #integer(0) #the file gtfile is empty

Comment: It seems that gt is still not being read in correctly.

Comment: Solution: I was trying to debug a script written for linux in the R environment. I added the "read.table" function without thinking, which I didn't need in the linux HPC environment. This was causing some slight modifications to my input file. I just needed to read in like this: gt="~/clean.tab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I was trying to debug a script written for linux in the R environment.
I added the "read.table" function without thinking, which I didn't need in the linux HPC environment.
This was causing some slight modifications to my input file. I just needed to read in like this:

```
gt="~/clean.tab"
```

Also, the above code was not strictly essential for the R environment. It was just checking that the files were there (not really reading in). The read in functions were further down in the code.